# applying a function across columns by extracting similar column names

Tags: r

My data looks like:

```
[[1]]
        date germany france germany_mean france_mean germany_sd france_sd
1 2016-01-01      17     25     21.29429    48.57103   30.03026  47.05169
```

What I am trying to do is to compute the following calculation over all the lists using `map`.

```
germany_calc = (germany - germany_mean) / germany_sd 
france_calc = (france - france_mean) / france_sd
```

However the number of columns can change - here there are two categories/countries but in another list there could be 1 or 3 or N. The countries always follow the same structure. That is,

```
"country1", "country2", ... , "countryN", "country1_mean", "country2_mean", ... , "countryN_mean", "country1_sd", "country2_sd", ... , "countryN_sd".
```

Expected Output (for the first list):

```
Germany: -0.1429988 =  (17 - 21.29429) / 30.03026 
France: -0.5009603 = (25 - 48.57103) / 47.05169
```

EDIT: Apologies - expected output:

```
-0.1429988
-0.5009603
```

Function:

```
Scale_Me <- function(x){
  (x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Data:

```
    my_list <- list(structure(list(date = structure(16801, class = "Date"), 
    germany = 17, france = 25, germany_mean = 21.2942922374429, 
    france_mean = 48.5710301846855, germany_sd = 30.030258443028, 
    france_sd = 47.0516928425878), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), structure(list(date = structure(16802, class = "Date"), 
    germany = 9, france = 29, germany_mean = 21.2993150684932, 
    france_mean = 48.5605316914534, germany_sd = 30.0286190461173, 
    france_sd = 47.0543871206842), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), structure(list(date = structure(16803, class = "Date"), 
    germany = 8, france = 18, germany_mean = 21.2947488584475, 
    france_mean = 48.551889593794, germany_sd = 30.0297291333284, 
    france_sd = 47.0562416513092), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), structure(list(date = structure(16804, class = "Date"), 
    germany = 3, france = 11, germany_mean = 21.2778538812785, 
    france_mean = 48.5382545766386, germany_sd = 30.0267943793948, 
    france_sd = 47.0607680244109), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), structure(list(date = structure(16805, class = "Date"), 
    germany = 4, france = 13, germany_mean = 21.2614155251142, 
    france_mean = 48.5214531240057, germany_sd = 30.0269420596686, 
    france_sd = 47.0676011750263), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), structure(list(date = structure(16806, class = "Date"), 
    germany = 4, france = 9, germany_mean = 21.253196347032, 
    france_mean = 48.5055948249362, germany_sd = 30.0292032528186, 
    france_sd = 47.0737183354519), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)))
```

Comment: Is there are reason your data can't be structured "long" with one row per country?

Comment: No! thats a good point and it just never occured to me to do this!. I will try to `pivot_longer` and then pivot it back using `pivot_wider`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is unclear on the exact form of output so we assume that what is wanted is a data frame with a column for date and a column for each country in which the country value is normalized.  In this case it means we want 3 columns in the output.

**1) pivot_longer/_wider** Bind the `my_list` list components together creating a data frame with a row from each component.  Then for each bare country name among the columns append _root to it so that every column name except `date` is of the form country_suffix.  Then convert to long form, perform the normalization and convert back to wide form:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

my_list %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  set_names(names(.)[1], sub("^([^_]*)$", "\\1_root", names(.)[-1])) %>%
  pivot_longer(-date, names_to = c("country", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(root = (root - mean) / sd) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "date", names_from = "country", values_from = "root")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  date       germany france
  <date>       <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2016-01-01  -0.143 -0.501
2 2016-01-02  -0.410 -0.416
3 2016-01-03  -0.443 -0.649
4 2016-01-04  -0.609 -0.798
5 2016-01-05  -0.575 -0.755
6 2016-01-06  -0.575 -0.839
```

**2) Base R**

After rbinding the list components together giving `d` we pick out the country names, `nms`, as those names not containing an underscore except for the first such (which is `date`).  Then perform the normalization and `cbind` the `date` column to that.

```
d <- do.call("rbind", my_list)
nms <- grep("_", names(d), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)[-1]
cbind(d[1], (d[nms] - d[paste0(nms, "_mean")]) / d[paste0(nms, "_sd")])
```

giving:

```
        date    germany     france
1 2016-01-01 -0.1429988 -0.5009603
2 2016-01-02 -0.4095864 -0.4157005
3 2016-01-03 -0.4427196 -0.6492633
4 2016-01-04 -0.6087181 -0.7976550
5 2016-01-05 -0.5748642 -0.7546901
6 2016-01-06 -0.5745473 -0.8392283
```

Comment: Thanks! I just got it working for one of my lists myself using `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`.

Comment: Nice ! I did not know these functions ;)

Answer (score 5):

Why not just `rbind` the thing?

```
with(do.call(rbind, my_list), 
     cbind(germany=(germany - germany_mean) / germany_sd,
           france=(france - france_mean) / france_sd))
#         germany     france
# [1,] -0.1429988 -0.5009603
# [2,] -0.4095864 -0.4157005
# [3,] -0.4427196 -0.6492633
# [4,] -0.6087181 -0.7976550
# [5,] -0.5748642 -0.7546901
# [6,] -0.5745473 -0.8392283
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you have to use `map` ?
Here I get your desired  output using two `for` loops instead of using `map`

```r
Result_list = vector("list",length(my_list))
for(i in 1:length(my_list))
{
  df = my_list[[i]]
  # identifier number of countries
  countries = colnames(df)[grep('mean',colnames(df))]
  countries = gsub("_mean","",countries)

  df_result = NULL
  for(j in 1:length(countries))
  {
    country = countries[j]
    value_country = df[1,match(country,colnames(df))]
    mean_country = df[1,match(paste0(country,"_mean"),colnames(df))]
    sd_country = df[1,match(paste0(country,"_sd"),colnames(df))]

    result_country = (value_country - mean_country) / sd_country
    Sentence = paste0(country,": ",round(result_country,5)," = (",value_country," - ",round(mean_country,5),") / ",round(sd_country,5))
    df_result = c(df_result,Sentence)
  }
  Result_list[[i]] = df_result
}
```

And the output `Result_list` looks like:

```r
> Result_list
[[1]]
[1] "germany: -0.143 = (17 - 21.29429) / 30.03026" 
[2] "france: -0.50096 = (25 - 48.57103) / 47.05169"

[[2]]
[1] "germany: -0.40959 = (9 - 21.29932) / 30.02862"
[2] "france: -0.4157 = (29 - 48.56053) / 47.05439" 

[[3]]
[1] "germany: -0.44272 = (8 - 21.29475) / 30.02973"
[2] "france: -0.64926 = (18 - 48.55189) / 47.05624"

[[4]]
[1] "germany: -0.60872 = (3 - 21.27785) / 30.02679"
[2] "france: -0.79765 = (11 - 48.53825) / 47.06077"

[[5]]
[1] "germany: -0.57486 = (4 - 21.26142) / 30.02694"
[2] "france: -0.75469 = (13 - 48.52145) / 47.0676" 

[[6]]
[1] "germany: -0.57455 = (4 - 21.2532) / 30.0292" 
[2] "france: -0.83923 = (9 - 48.50559) / 47.07372"
```

Is it what you are looking for ?

**EDIT: Extracting only results**

For extracting only result values, you can do the following:

```r
Df_result_value = NULL
for(i in 1:length(my_list))
{
  df = my_list[[i]]
  # identifier number of countries
  countries = colnames(df)[grep('mean',colnames(df))]
  countries = gsub("_mean","",countries)

  for(j in 1:length(countries))
  {
    country = countries[j]
    value_country = df[1,match(country,colnames(df))]
    mean_country = df[1,match(paste0(country,"_mean"),colnames(df))]
    sd_country = df[1,match(paste0(country,"_sd"),colnames(df))]

    result_country = (value_country - mean_country) / sd_country

    Df_result_value = rbind(Df_result_value,c(country,result_country))
  }
}
Df_result_value = data.frame(Df_result_value)
colnames(Df_result_value) = c("Country","Result")
```

And get this output:

```r
> Df_result_value
   Country             Result
1  germany -0.142998843835787
2   france -0.500960300483614
3  germany -0.409586436512588
4   france -0.415700488060442
5  germany -0.442719572974515
6   france -0.649263275639099
7  germany -0.608718121899195
8   france -0.797654950237258
9  germany -0.574864249939699
10  france -0.754690110335453
11 germany -0.574547256608035
12  france -0.839228262008441
```

Comment: I am saving this because I really like the output. I was probably a little unclear in the expected output. I just wanted the values. `-0.143, -0.50096`. I am going to use this for something I wanted to do which is similar to your output. Thanks!

Comment: @user113156, you're welcome ! Glad you can use it. If you just want the values, you can extract only the `result_country` variable and make a dataframe from it

Comment: I edited my answer to provide some code for extracting only the result values.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `transform` as well in `base R`

```
transform(do.call(rbind, my_list), 
  germany = (germany - germany_mean)/germany_sd, 
   france = (france - france_mean)/france_sd)[c('date', 'germany', 'france')]
#     date    germany     france
#1 2016-01-01 -0.1429988 -0.5009603
#2 2016-01-02 -0.4095864 -0.4157005
#3 2016-01-03 -0.4427196 -0.6492633
#4 2016-01-04 -0.6087181 -0.7976550
#5 2016-01-05 -0.5748642 -0.7546901
#6 2016-01-06 -0.5745473 -0.8392283
```

---

Or in `dplyr`, without any reshaping, this can be done

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(my_list) %>% 
   transmute(date,
             germany = (germany - germany_mean)/germany_sd,
             france = (france - france_mean)/france_sd)
```